# React event target value from jsx element does not get bind to state and json array (Type error cannot read the properties of undefined )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, jsx

I am trying to bind the value from an event from select option tag which has data fetched from mongodb for locations which is populated on the select dropdown during componentDidMount() lifecycle method call.

I want to achieve a functionality in which when I select a value from select drop the corresponding values from other api (restaurants) should get populated.

but the problem is fetch url promise does not seem to resolve and does not bind to state.restaurants array to create ul elements in input type text box. here is my code

```
export default class Vrestauranthome extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('Home is called vrestaurant');
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
      restaurants: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Wallpaper componentDidMount getting called....', this.state);

    fetch('http://localhost:5252/zomato/locations', { method: 'GET' })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ locations: data.data }));
  }

  fetchRestaurants = (event) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5252/zomato/restaurants/${event.target.value}`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ restaurants: data.data });
        console.log(data.data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.locations || !this.state.restaurants) {
      return <>Loading data...</>;
    }
    
    let locationList =
      this.state.locations.length &&
      this.state.locations.map((item) => (
        <option key={item.name} value={item.city_id}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      ));

    let restaurantList = this.state.restaurants.length && (
      <ul>
        {this.state.restaurants.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );

    return (
      <div className='ContainerHome'>
        <div className='location-selector' style={{ paddingLeft: '90px' }}>
          <select
            className='locationDropdown px-3'
            onChange={this.fetchRestaurants}
          >
            <option value='0' style={{ display: 'none' }}>
              Please type a location
            </option>
            {locationList}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className='restaurantSelector' style={{ paddingLeft: '90px' }}>
          <input
            className='searchForRestaurantinputBOX'
            type='text'
            placeholder='  Search for restaurants'
            style={{
              paddingLeft: '50px',
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              opacity: '85%',
            }}
          />
          {restaurantList}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

when I use fetch method to get the data from url using the event.target.value, it shows the value when I console log it but it seems to not bind with the url used to get data from the mongodb DB using the backend api routes.

this is in mongo db as Locations and Restaurants collections respectively.

I map city_id from locations to Restaurants.city to get values to populate in search input box.

```
[{"name":"ShalimarBhagh, Delhi","city_id":"1","location_id":"1","country_name":"India"}]

[{"name":"Gulab","city_name":"Delhi","city":"1","area":"11"}]
```

when I select an option from the drop it just goes of and throws error below:
**it shows error in the browser: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**

here what shows up in the inspect browser when i select something from  :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries and also making functional component same like this I found the error.

It should be `data => this.setState({restaurants:data.result})`. it gets the results back after update.

This is because in backend it return results variable after getting data from mongoose models. Shheesh.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the data have been loaded before displaying them.
Adding a check in the `render` method should prevent the error:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.locations || !this.state.restaurants) {
      return <>Loading data...</>;
    }
    
    let locationList =
      this.state.locations.length &&
      this.state.locations.map((item) => (
        <option key={item.name} value={item.city_id}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      ));

    let restaurantList = this.state.restaurants.length && (
      <ul>
        {this.state.restaurants.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );

    ...
}
```

Also, try to change your `setState` calls like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5252/zomato/locations', { method: 'GET' })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) =>
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      locations: data.data,
    })
  );

...

fetch(`http://localhost:5252/zomato/restaurants/${event.target.value}`, {
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, restaurants: data.data });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that added the code after render() but data comes as undefined in console.log and my tags get disappear and replaced by Loading....., Any suggestion why it comes as undefined

Comment: Try to see the edited answer

Comment: I changed the code to data => data.result it works fine after lots of hits. Shishh. Thanks for your help.